# Form validation: un-hide submit button when a radio value is selected and text message is entered

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I just want my "submit" button to un-hide (so user can push it) when a radio button is selected and a message is entered in the text box.

I'm using ruby on rails, but I think this may be a javascript/css question. please let me know.

(Also i'm using formalize for the form styling)

Comment: You should start with the Submit button visible but use JavaScript to hide it (CSS `visibility: hidden`) on page load / document ready. That way any users who have JavaScript disabled will still be able to use your page. Look into the `onclick` event for the radio button and `onkeyup` for the text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an onchange (or onclick) event listener to the radio button and a keyup event listener to the text box, then check the values. http://jsfiddle.net/vHdBb/1/